# Structuring C++ Application (directory and folders)

Tags: c++

I'm coming from web development and I need to ask C++ programmers how do they manage their directory for a model-based project?

I have structured my project in Visual Studio C++ Solution Manager like this:

```
-> Header Files
   --> Models
       DatabaseEngine.interface.h

-> Resources

-> Source Files
   --> Models
       DatabaseEngine.cpp
   --> Application
       Core.cpp
       Bootstrap.cpp
   --> FrontController
       ---
```

I have made an exact duplicate of Model's directory under the Headers directory, and appended them with `".interface"` name, since they are interfaces and the real implementation of them lies in the mirror path under the `Sources`.

And I have custom types such as `DBConnection` which I don't know where to put them? should i put them in a file named `CustomTypes.cpp` or I should relate them to their associated parent model/class/object?

My concern is the convention and standards.

Comment: I am not sure there is a convention. Every project seems to do something slightly different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not any standard, C++ is a very open-minded world you will see ; )

It is all about making what works best for you, but usually taking advices from people that have already experimented cannot hurt.
Personally, I try to follow this convention

```
/ProjectName
    /src
        /libs <- Libraries go here
            /Models <- Assuming you want to make a library out of your models
                User.h
                User.cpp
                ... <- Putting header and implementations together is not a problem,
                       they should be edited in parallel oftentimes
                /Utilities <- Should your library grow, you can make it more modular
                              by creating subdirectories
                              (that could contain subdirectories, etc.)
                    DBConnection.h
                    DBConnection.cpp

        /apps <- define your applications here.
                 They probably rely on classes and functions defined in one or several of your libaries define above.
            /ApplicationA
                Core.h
                Core.cpp
                Bootstrap.h
                Bootstrap.cpp
    /resources
    /doc

    # Below are 'environment specific' folders.
    /vs <- Visual studio project files
    /xcode <- Xcode project files
```

## Remarks

### Headers and implementations

- Header files (.h, or .hpp, or no extension) are indeed defining the interface that will be implemented in the implementation file (.cpp). Nonetheless, it is very common to give the same basename to both, and only distinguish them by extension(or absence of). Adding an additional `.interface` part probably does not buy you much, and could confuse your IDE (or other tools), that is otherwise able to relate a header file to its implementation file.
- For the same reason (not confusing some tools), it can be easier to put both files in the same folder: they are very closely related anyway.

  - Additionally, if later on you need to change your folders structures (eg. to modularize), having only one place to make subfolders (instead of two in your approach) will also make life a bit easier.

### Custom types

C++ offers **classes** for the programmer to define custom types.  It is very common to define custom types in their own pair of header/implementation file. In your case, `DBConnection.h` would **define** a DBConnection class, whose (non-inline) methods would be implemented in `DBConnection.cpp`.

Personnaly, I would not be afraid to create one pair of files per type, which makes it easier for future-you and other programmers to find the file defining a type. You can manage the growing number of files by making subfolders, that will force you to modularize your design.

Of course, sometimes you will need to define a very short class, tightly coupled to another class. It is up to you to include both classes in a common pair of files if you feel the link between them is strong enough.

### Extensibility

It may not be a concern to all projects, but this directory structure is extensible in terms of environments and build management.
Keeping project files in separate folders at the top level, and defining out-of-source builds, allows to create project files for other IDEs further down the line.

This hierarchy is also easily amenable to CMake build management, if you should go this way. A `CMakeLists.txt` file will be placed at the top level (under ProjectName/), this file invoking `add_subdirectory(src)`, in turn caling a `CMakeLists.txt` in ProjectName/src/, etc.

Comment: There may not be a standard but there are some very strong conventions – such as putting header files separately from implementation files.

Comment: I can say you that Visual Studio has put two separate directories for source (.cpp) and header (.h), it seems it recommends you to separate them physically...

Comment: @KonradRudolph If anything I have seen people moving away from having separate include directories. This has advantages such as making it easier for tooling to find corresponding header files for example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In no project have I seen headers being seperate from source files. There is no convention.

Comment: @sjdowling For libraries, having separate header files is almost a must. Of course that doesn’t *have* to be in the source structure (the install script can take care of that), but it’s customary to have it like that.

Comment: @cybermonkey Then you didn’t look very hard. Simple as that. It’s by no means a universal convention of course. More generally though, there certainly *are* rough conventions. The GNU guidelines for instance have one (although they don’t specify whether to separate source and header files).

Comment: @KonradRudolph `they don't specify whether to separate source and header files`.

Comment: @cybermonkey … so? You’ve said “There is no convention”. That’s just patently untrue, as my example shows. You’ve also said “In no project have I seen headers being seperate from source files” and that may well be true, but it’s not terribly indicative because such projects do exist.